# How to make keypress handle Enter

Tags: c#, winforms, events

We can handle (cancel) the key press events in .net winforms.However it doesnot work for not character keys such as Enter,Up,Down etc.
But I need to handle these also ,Is there a way to do it?

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The above code will not allow you to type any character .But , you will be able to press enter for multiline which is what we want to make sure doesnot happen.

Note: I required this to make sure that barcode reader doesnot send the last enter key.

Comment: What do you mean ? You want to raise an event when enter key is pressed?

Comment: No @Syed I want to make the control think that nothing was pressed when I press enter. ,It can be done for other keys with above code..not for enter..

Comment: I think it will work now , thanks ! I just made a correction to KeyDown and +1

Comment: Pleasure bro I also think `e.Handled = true` should also work... Check the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the event when Enter key is pressed just like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     e.SuppressKeyPress = true; 
}
```

[KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: event should be keydown

Comment: Microsoft is wrong !Try the sample in link it does not work ! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -2):

You can use keyPress or KeyDown event.

1. KeyPress

   ```
   private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
       //// Method 1
       if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
       {
           // Enter code here
       }

       //// Method 2
       if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
       {
           // Enter code here
       }
   }
   ```
2. KeyDown

   ```
   private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
       {
           // Enter code here
       }
   }
   ```